# Phrase that Means Have a Long Happy Life

Tags: phrase, idiom

My boss is German and retires this week. I'd like to sign the note I'm sending her with a German phrase or idiomatic phrase that means something like, "have a long and happy life."

I've looked on a couple of German language sites that list German idioms, but everything listed concerned day-to-day life ("Morgenstund hat Gold im Mund", "Da haben wir den Salat," etc.)

I'm looking for an idiom or folksy phrase that would seem to have come from a person whose first language is German, not just a literal translation of "have a long happy life."  Perhaps there's no such phrase. I speak a tiny bit of German only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different sample texts/whishes on the internet about the retirement of a colleague/employee.

Here is an example text that best suits your needs:

> Alles Gute für den neuen Lebensabschnitt. Genießen Sie die Ruhestandszeit in vollen Zügen!

Check out this [link](https://www.pinterest.de/amp/pin/774548835894714345/) to see more examples.

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you.

Comment: *Genieß* oder *Genießen Sie*

Comment: "Die Ruhestandszeit" klingt aber arg hölzern, wie auch "Lebensabschnitt". "Genießen Sie den Ruhestand" sagt man schon eher. Wieso nicht "langes, glückliches Leben"?